# Roblox Studio Camera change with spawn

Tags: roblox, luau

so I have a problem with my 2D camera
so I'm making a 2D game on Roblox, and it's a 1v1 duel game so 1 player
spawns on the left side and 1 on the right side and I have my 2D cam script which lets the camera goes a bit more to the left so if you spawn on the left side everything looks good
but if you spawn on the right side, the camera is too much to the left.
Does someone know how I can make that the camera X Axis changes with the spawn?

I already tried it with chatgpt but he couldnt help so maybe here someone can help me

Comment: Rather than having the camera focus on the players, try calculate the midpoint of all the players' positions and follow that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.